# AWS Fargate container not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I've created a Fargate task that has a web server container. The task has an eni which appears to have a public IP. The container definition for the web server has port mapping for port 443. But when I inspect the container, network bindings are not configured. And I cannot access the web server using the public IP address. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Have you validate you're in a public subnet? And checked the container definitions are using the port mapping for the correct container

Comment: Yes to both of those. And I found the problem, I had not set the proper inbound rules on the security group associated with the ENI

Comment: Glad you solved it, have a great weekend :D

Answer (score 10):

I needed to add the proper inbound rules for the security group associated with the ENI

Comment: what did you exactly do, I have the same problem...

Comment: this fixed it for me. from the tasks details, click on the ENI details and edit your inbound rules

Comment: Thanks a lot! this was the issue. I added a new rule to the security group to allow inbound traffic from "my ip address" and bingo- immediately see the public IP accessible.